# stop multiple selection from on dropdown

Tags: jquery, html

I have a html dropdown. Values are multi selected, i want, user only able to select one value at a time

```
<select name="selectto" id="ddlQuestionList" multiple="multiple">
  <option></option>
</select>
```

[image: dropdown with multiple selection]

[image: this happening when removing that multiple='multiple' attribute.]
i want like first image. Not like second one with dropdown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply

remove `multiple="multiple"` from the tag and add `size=10` or whatever size you like (Y)

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/x3cfb/

Comment: if i will remove this attribute multiple=multiple. then, i will not able to make dropdown like a textarea wide. As you can see in image, that is a dropdown. user don't want to click again and again on dropdown.

Comment: thank you for your help, and i also have to add overflow:scroll. so that, it will not extend more in height, on increasing of value.

Comment: @wikijames use maximum height in css `#ddlQuestionList{
    max-height:100px;
}`  http://jsfiddle.net/x3cfb/3/

Answer (score 2):

Remove the multiple attribute:

```
<select name="selectto " id="ddlQuestionList">
```

Boolean attributes are false if they are not included, true if they appear at all `<select multiple>` and true if you use the full XML style syntax `<select multiple="multiple">`

Comment: If, however, you are using the `multiple` attribute so it appears as a list, you need to use `size="7"` or such instead.

Comment: Technically, you don't have to as you can multi-select from a drop-down, but from a usability point of view it is much easier - so +1 for using the `size` attribute.

Comment: thanks allot, i also have to add overflow:scroll. so that, it will not extend more in height, on increasing of value.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `multiple` attribute, like so:

```
<select name="selectto" id="ddlQuestionList">
  <option></option>
</select>
```